# BeautifulSoup webscrape .asp only searches last in list

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup

```
def get_NYSE_tickers():

 an = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
       'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W',
       'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0']

 for value in an:
     resp = requests.get(
         'https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies={}'.format(value))
     soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
     table = soup.find('table', class_='market tab1')
     tickers = []
     for row in table.findAll('tr', class_='ts1',)[0:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
         tickers.append(ticker)
     for row in table.findAll('tr', class_='ts0',)[0:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
         tickers.append(ticker)
     with open("NYSE.pickle", "wb") as f:
         while("" in tickers):
             tickers.remove("")
         pickle.dump(tickers, f)

 print(tickers)


get_NYSE_tickers()
```

My problem is that when I run this script my output is only the data contained in the '0' page. Its always the last value in the list.

Also I would like to know if there is a way to combine the

```
for row in table.findAll('tr', class_='ts1',)[0:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
         tickers.append(ticker)
     for row in table.findAll('tr', class_='ts0',)[0:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
         tickers.append(ticker)
```

into one block of code as class_='ts0','ts1' doesn't seem to quite get it.

I would like to see all ticker symbols from
https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=A, https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=B,
https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=C etc. etc.

in a single pickle or csv file:

"['AVX', 'AHC', 'RNT', 'AAN', 'AXF', 'DVK', 'RCW', 'SAD', 'ABB', 'ANF', 'ABM', 'IMW', 'SZM', 'SZI', 'ICT', 'ACN', 'ABD', 'ATN', 'AYI', 'AEA', 'ASX', 'ACM', 'AEG', 'AEB', 'AEH', 'AET', 'AMG', 'AG', 'A', 'ADC', 'AGU', 'APD', 'ARG', 'AQD', 'ALZ', 'ALF', 'ALK', 'ALB', 'ALU', 'ACL', 'AXB', 'ARE', 'AYE', 'AGN', 'AMO', 'ADS', 'AOI', 'AZM', 'AIB', 'ALY', 'ALM', 'ALJ', 'AWP', 'AMB', 'AKT', 'ACO', 'HES', 'AMX', 'ACC', 'AEP', 'AXP', 'AFE', 'AIG', 'AVF', 'AOB', 'ARP', 'AWR', 'AVD', 'ACF', 'AGP', 'AMN', 'AHS', 'AP', 'AXR', 'AU', 'NLY', 'ATV', 'ANH', 'APA', 'AIT', 'WTR', 'ARB', 'ARJ', 'ADM', 'AWI', 'ARM', 'AHT', 'AHL', 'AGO', 'AZN', 'ATO', 'ATT', 'AUO', 'AN', 'NEH', 'AVR', 'AXA', 'AZZ', 'AKS', 'AAR', 'AIR', 'RNT.A', 'AAN.A', 'CBJ', 'SQT', 'IWK', 'EOA', 'REU', 'MHG', 'ABT', 'AKR', 'BJV', 'ODY', 'RDF', 'MKY', 'BFN', 'ACE', 'ATU', 'ADX', 'ASF', 'AAP', 'AEO', 'AEV', 'AED', 'AER', 'AES', 'ACS', 'AFL', 'AGCO', 'AEM', 'GRO', 'NOW', 'AYR', 'AAI', 'ALQ', 'ABA', 'ALG', 'AIN', 'ACV', 'AA', 'AFN', 'ALX', 'Y', 'ATI', 'ALE', 'AB', 'AZ', 'AFC', 'ALL', 'ANR', 'MO', 'ACH', 'ABK', 'AKF', 'AEE', 'AXL', 'ADY', 'AEL', 'AFG', 'AM', 'AFF', 'ANL', 'ARL', 'ASI', 'AMT', 'AWK', 'APU', 'ABC', 'AME', 'AMP', 'APH', 'APC', 'AGL', 'AXE', 'AHR', 'AOC', 'AIV', 'ATR', 'ARA', 'ABR', 'ACI', 'ARD', 'ARW', 'ABG', 'ASH', 'ALC', 'AIZ', 'AF', 'ATG', 'AHD', 'T', 'ATW', 'ALV', 'AZO', 'AVB', 'AVY', 'AVA', 'AVP', 'AXS' ...]"

Comment: What kind of expected result are you look for?

Comment: I am expecting a list of ticker symbols, scraped from the table data on "https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=A" and https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=B" etc. etc.

Comment: currently the output is "[['PAR', 'SE', 'GJW', 'KDE', 'NDN']]" which is a good scrape of the "https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=0" page, but it leaves off all the data from A-Z pages. It only scrapes the last value in the list.

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml') try that out.

Comment: Negative: soup =  BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml') still only returns the values for the last value in the initially supplied list "an"

Comment: oh i see the problem it's the initializing of the ticker

Comment: You empty it every loop and than print it after so it's only once.

Comment: If you put the tickers[] outside the loop it should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed resp.text to resp.content and it printed all of them.
Also your emptying the array every time. Put the tickers[] outside the loop or print it everytime in the loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

def get_NYSE_tickers():

 an = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
       'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W',
       'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0']
 tickers = []
 for value in an:
     resp = requests.get(
         'https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies={}'.format(value))
     soup =  BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')
     table = soup.find('table', class_='market tab1')
     for row in table.findAll('tr', class_='ts1')[0:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
         tickers.append(ticker)
     for row in table.findAll('tr', class_='ts0')[0:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
         tickers.append(ticker)
print(tickers)
get_NYSE_tickers()
```

Comment: tickers = []


inside the loop is the problem. Thanks man!

Comment: Yeah was emptying it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd


goals = list(ascii_uppercase)


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        allin = []
        for goal in goals:
            r = req.get(url.format(goal))
            df = pd.read_html(r.content, header=1)[-1]
            target = df['Symbol'].tolist()
            allin.extend(target)
    print(allin)


main("https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies={}")
```

Comment: Close...the output CSV file contains data from more than one column. It doesn't simply list the tickers, but has the name of the company as well as the ticker.

Comment: @AaronDKat [edit] your question and include a sample of desired _output_

Comment: I was hoping it would come out in a CSV or pickle file to be saved for later use.

Comment: @AaronDKat in which shape to be shown in `CSV` file ? Vertical or horizontal

Comment: horizontal.

However, this code is completely different from mine and I have very little understanding of how it works.

Is there any chance you could explain why my code only returns the ticker symbols for the last value in the list 'an'? (which is https://www.advfn.com/nyse/newyorkstockexchange.asp?companies=0)